# detecting a 404 on a http get and quickly handling it

Tags: angular

I got this HTTP get request:

```
this.httpService.getData ('http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/' + 'badReferenceHere').subscribe(
          (response: Response) => {
            let apiResponse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
            this.post_content = apiResponse.content.rendered;
            // do something with the this.post_content
          },
          (error: any) => {
            this.post_content = 'An error has occurred.';
        });
```

If the URL is missing, and you already got a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` message on the dev tools console.log, but yet, your code still showing the spinner, what are you supposed to do to quickly detect this and stop the wait and handle the 404 to say a message such as "That link does not exist"?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question: check if the status code is 404 and do whatever you want to do ...

Comment: Also, what do you intend to achieve with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle this in your error handler:

```
this.httpService.getData ('http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/' + 'badReferenceHere').subscribe(
      (response: Response) => {
        let apiResponse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
        this.post_content = apiResponse.content.rendered;
        // do something with the this.post_content
      },
      (error: any) => {
        this.post_content = 'An error has occurred: ' + error.message ;
        alert(this.post_content);
        //Code to stop spinner
    });
```

Comment: apologies from all! I realized what the problem was when I was posting the question and I went and fixed my code. ( I was not updating the spinner with the response! that's it. ). And as soon as I fixed the code, I came back and I deleted the question. But apparently, I did not! And you guys answered.  I will just accept one of the correct answers with my apologies!

Answer (score 1):

```js
GetMethod(url): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get(url, { body: "" })
            .map(res => <any>res.json());
    }
```